# Rails update from 5.2.4 to 5.2.5 breaks assets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Before a deployment, I ran bundle install and bundle update. Then my Rails version switched from 5.2.4 to 5.2.5, and several gems were upgraded too. Everything is still working perfectly in development environment.

But problems appeared after deploying to production environment. I have the following issue, which I think is related to assets. Any page I request, the following message ends up in the log file:

```
I, [2021-04-22T22:48:43.887632 #7620]  INFO -- :   Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (11.6ms)
I, [2021-04-22T22:48:44.149881 #7620]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 294ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
F, [2021-04-22T22:48:44.150616 #7620] FATAL -- :   
F, [2021-04-22T22:48:44.150738 #7620] FATAL -- : ActionView::Template::Error (application.css):
F, [2021-04-22T22:48:44.150992 #7620] FATAL -- :      
 9:   <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)).html_safe %></title>
10: 
11:   <link href="/assets/oblique-4.1.1/styles/images/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon">
12:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
13:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
14:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
15:   <%= render "layouts/shim" %>
F, [2021-04-22T22:48:44.151084 #7620] FATAL -- :   
F, [2021-04-22T22:48:44.151184 #7620] FATAL -- : app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__255798539_93007000'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in index'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:21:in `index'
```

This happens only in the production environment, of which configurationis given by the untouched production.rb file:

```
DataQualityManager::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  # config.assets.debug = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass --> automatically used due to sass-rails gem

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = false

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  # config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Store uploaded files locally.
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Define connection to email services
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'l021000110029b.adr.admin.ch/' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

end
```

The Gemfile contains:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sassc-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '~> 4.0'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.2'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.6'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1'
gem 'd3-rails'
gem 'js_cookie_rails'
gem 'httparty', '~> 0.14'
gem 'nested_form_fields'
gem 'pg'
gem 'deep_cloneable', '~> 3.0'
#gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 6.0'
gem 'tzinfo-data'
gem 'audited', '~> 4.9'
gem 'awesome_print' # Layout enhancement for Audited

# Generate SQL scripts via renderer
gem 'sql_query'

# Workflow support
gem 'workflow-activerecord', '>= 4.1', '< 6.0'

# Full-text search with Postgres
gem 'pg_search'

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'

# XLSX format support
gem 'write_xlsx'
gem 'write_xlsx_rails', git: 'https://github.com/fchampreux/write_xlsx_rails.git', branch: 'master'
gem 'roo'

# Authentication and Authorisations
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-security'
gem 'email_address' # for email validation
gem 'cancancan', '~> 3.0'

# MarkDown parser
gem 'redcarpet', '~> 3.5'
# eMail notification support
gem 'mailgun-ruby', '~>1.1'

# gem for dev and test only
group :development, :test, :validation do
  gem 'annotate', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails', '~> 6.0'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 3.15'
  gem 'database_cleaner-active_record'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~>3.140'
end
```

Can you help me understand what causes the failure after the upgrade?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you have a diff of Gemfile.lock, which Gems where updated too? Try reverting sassc-rails and/or coffee-rails for instance. That could be related to assets, css in particular.

Comment: I solved a part of the solution when downgrading d3-rails to 5.9.2. The development instance now runs both with -e development or -e production options. But the production, relying on passenger does not... still searching based on the date of the update ...